# How to merge Lable merge field in silverlight 4 richtext box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datasource

i'm want to do this in silverlight 4, actually i'm doing mail merge module in silverlight 4 richtextbox. i want to insert label fields when mail merge field click on the mail merge tab. how can i acheive this. What i need to do?

i added the FirstName,LastName and the Job title. now what i want to do is just to insert First name in richtextbox whenever the first name clicked from the Mail Merge tab.

[image]

```
public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            return employees;
        }
    }
private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
                {
                    new Employee()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Andrew",
                        LastName = "Fuller", 
                        JobTitle = "Director - Finance",
                    }, 
                    new Employee()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Nancy",
                        LastName = "Davolio", 
                        JobTitle = "Director - Human Resources",
                    },
                    new Employee()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Robert",
                        LastName = "King", 
                        JobTitle = "Engineering Design Manager",
                    },
                    new Employee()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Margaret",
                        LastName = "Peacock", 
                        JobTitle = "Finance & Investments Officer",
                    }
                };
```